# Unable to connect to docker container which includes a postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker instance and I have changed the file =:

```
"/var/lib/postgreqsql/data/pg_hba.conf"
```

And it now has errors.

It appears that this is preventing me actually connecting to the docker instance.

```
docker logs --tail 20 postgres

2022-08-04 00:30:26.392 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-04 00:30:26.392 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-04 00:30:26.417 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-04 00:30:26.451 UTC [1] LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2022-08-04 00:30:26.451 UTC [1] CONTEXT:  line 87 of configuration file "/var/lib/postgreqsql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2022-08-04 00:30:26.451 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
2022-08-04 00:30:26.453 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

When I try and connect I get a consistent message as follows:

```
root@VM01:~/vm01-docker# docker exec -u root -it postgres bash
Error response from daemon: Container 4545dcba980215c is restarting, wait until the container is running
root@VM01:~/vm01-docker#
```

Stopping and starting as follows:

```
docker-compose stop postgres
docker-compose start postgres
```

Has no impact the issue remains.

What I need to do is be able to connect again to the instance and edit the file pg_hba.conf again to correct the fault but I am not sure how I can. (I am a docker newb.)

Comment: How did you originally start the container?  How did you set that configuration option to start with?

Comment: docker-compose up -d postgres --> Everything is from here. https://docs.opencve.io/installation/docker/ Basically all of the config is set out of the box. I believe it is in the associated yml file. Everything was working until I made the change to the postgresql config file and now I can't start the container again as it hits this error and reboots in a loop.